# Can I use css to always keep element as first child

Tags: css

I have a div with elements that may dynamically get added and removed. Is it possible to define a css class that makes sure that the corresponding element is always displayed as the first child of the div (i.e. on top)

Or do I need to attach an on change event listener to the div to move the child to the top via js?

Comment: How are the new elements being populated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `display: flex` on the parent, then use the `order` attribute on the child to put it where you want.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.first {
  order: -1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>asdf</li>
  <li>asdf</li>
  <li class="first">first</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

here's the fix:

HTML

```
<div>
  <p>Must not be first 1</p>
  <p>Must not be first 2</p>
  <p class="first">Must be first</p>
  <p>Must not be first 3</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:column wrap;
}

.first {
  order:-1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rp1m8874/

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hacky, but you can add a class to the one that needs to stay first and then set `position: absolute; top: 0` on it. You'll have to push all other elements down by the first one's height though.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.container div {
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}
.container div.first {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    another div
  </div>
  <div class="first">
    I should be first
  </div>
  <div>
    another div
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you are using Jquery :

```
$("#yourContainer").prepend("<div>This div will be first!</div>");
```